# Database design scenario for budget (whole and daily)

Tags: database-design, nosql

**Scenario**: Each user add funds to his account, for example 100 USD, and he defines that the system (our website) could spend up-to 10 USD per day for showing his ads in the website. each time his ad is shown in or website, it's gonna cost him 1 USD.

**P.S**: we're not inserting a record into the database every time his ad is shown, we just `deduct` the amount for showing his ad (`1 USD`) from his whole budget.

because we're showing too many ads, it's not possible to insert a record for each ad show into the database.

I have 2 columns in users table, `whole_budget` and `daily_budget`, so for the above user `whole_budget` is `100` and `daily_budget` is `10`.

in the above scenario, how can we manage `daily budget`? so when an ad is shown, how we're gonna deduct 1 USD from his account?

how can we know if he has left daily budget? so we can decide to show his ad for the rest of the day or not.

I would appreciate your help

EDIT ---------------

This could be simply achieved by having a table called `shown_ads`, and every time we show an ad, we insert a record in this table with the respected DATE() so we can later on calculate the amount of his budget already spent today. but imagine we're showing `1M` ads each day, so *what I believe* is that it's not good to insert 1M records every day! It's just a case-study, I want to know how would you implement this.

Comment: Any good adserver *will* store *every ad shown*, and also *to which user (or cookie, or IP)*, *at which time*, and whether and when *the user clicked*. That's the only way to really be able to tell how efficient your ads are; and develop strategies to decide *what* to show *to whom* and *when* in a (close-to) optimal fashion. This involves a large dataset (and a good deal of analytics, machine learning and other IA). Sure enough. Be ready for it. And probably, don't be overzealous: if the customer paid 10 USD and you showed 11 ads (because you had more visitors than anticipated); be happy.

Comment: As i said, it's just a case study, it's not happening in the real world, I want to know how this could be implemented without having an extra table (which is obviously gonna get big after a while) and making troubles querying. thanks for the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution (probably) would be:

Have one table for the whole budget for each campaign (let users have more than one ad at a time :-):

```
CREATE TABLE budget
(
    campaign_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(user_id),
    /* Assumption: your currency doesn't have decimals; or you're using cents
       as currency unit */
    original_budget    INTEGER NOT NULL,  
    available_budget   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    daily_budget_limit INTEGER NOT NULL,

    -- Security checks
    CHECK(original_budget > 0),
    CHECK(original_budget >= available_budget),
    CHECK(daily_budget_limit > 0),
    CHECK(daily_budget_limit <= original_budget)
) ;
```

Have a *second* table for the budget of just *today*

```
CREATE TABLE todays_budget
(
    campaign_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES budget(campaign_id) PRIMARY KEY,
    original_daily_budget INTEGER NOT NULL,
    available_daily_budget INTEGER NOT NULL,

    CHECK(available_daily_budget >= 0)
) ;
```

Every day, at 00:00, perform the following operations:

1. Subtract the `spent_budget` (`original_daily_budget - available_daily_budget`) from the `budget`
2. `DELETE` everything from `todays_budget`
3. `INSERT` new rows to `todays_budget`, with both original_daily and available_daily budget equal to the min of (daily_budget_limit, available_budget)

This can be done with the following queries:

1. Subtract remaining from *yesterday*

   ```
   UPDATE 
       budget
   SET
       available_budget = available_budget - 
           (SELECT
               original_daily_budget - available_daily_budget
           FROM
               todays_budget tod
           WHERE
               tod.campaign_id = budget.campaign_id)
    WHERE
         campaign_id IN 
             (SELECT 
                 campaign_id 
             FROM 
                 todays_budget 
             WHERE 
                  available_daily_budget > 0
             ) ;
   ```
2. Clear out everything from *todays_budget*

   ```
   DELETE
   FROM todays_budget ;
   ```
3. And fill it up again

   ```
   INSERT INTO todays_budget
      (campaign_id, original_daily_budget, available_daily_budget)
   SELECT
       campaign_id, 
       CASE WHEN available_budget > daily_budget_limit then
           daily_budget_limit
       ELSE
           available_budget
       END AS original_daily_budget,
       CASE WHEN available_budget > daily_budget_limit then
           daily_budget_limit
       ELSE
           available_budget
       END AS available_daily_budget
   FROM
       budget
   WHERE
       available_budget > 0 ;
   ```

And very time you show an ad: Subtract one from `available_daily_budget`

```
UPDATE 
    todays_budget
SET 
    available_daily_budget = available_daily_budget - 1
WHERE 
    campaign_id = ((the corresponding campaign_id)) ;
```

---

**Notes**

1. I'm using SQL to describe your scenario. It is possible to do the same with noSQL databses. I wouldn't. This works well under a relational model.
2. If using SQL, steps 1 through 3 should be wrapped in a transaction, under `SET ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`; to avoid concurrency issues. If any of the *check constraints* fails, the whole transaction will be aborted and you'll have to retry it as a whole.
3. I've tried to use SQL Standard as much as possible, specific databases could allow for (slightly) simpler queries.
4. I am ignoring very many details that should be taking into consideration in a realistic situation.

Comment: thanks you, another thing, if we're showing 100.000 ads per day, would you go with a `shown_ads` table? so inserting 100.000 records per day, is that ok?

Comment: If you **earn** money showing ads; and specially if you earn money for *clicks*, spend the needed amount for your infrastructure. I would go for `shown_ads` in most scenarios (100 K, 100 M, 100 G). That doesn't mean your `shown_ads` cannot coexist with this solution. Redundancy is not *always* bad.